# Maven Bundle Plugin: Export has private references

Tags: java, osgi, bnd, maven-bundle-plugin

After updating the `maven-bundle-plugin` from version `2.3.5` to version `2.4.0` running `mvn clean install` outputs some warning messages, which I don't fully understand. E.g.

`Export ch.entwine.weblounge.contentrepository.impl.index,  has 1,  private references [org.elasticsearch.action.bulk]`

I guess this has something to do with an embedded lib (elasticsearch). Here are parts of the POM:

```
<dependencies>
  ...
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>0.19.9</version>
  </dependency>
  ...
</dependencies
...
<Export-Package>
  ...
  ch.entwine.weblounge.contentrepository.impl.index
  ...
</Export-Package>
<Embed-Dependency>
  ....
  elasticsearch;inline=true
  ...
</Embed-Dependency>
```

What does the error message exactly mean?
What is the recommended way to solve such problems?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That message means that inside one of your public packages (that you are exporting) there is a class that is accessing a class that is in a private package (a package that is not being exported).

When embedding jars you must not use Export-Package to declare packages from the embedded jars. it is for you declare the packages from the own bundle. You must use <_exportcontents> to export org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works! But I was always thinking that packages from embedded dependencies should not be exported (not be part of the bundle api). Am I wrong on this?

Comment: well, that depends... if you are embedding a jar is because it doesn't exists as a bundle, so you can't set it scope as "provided". so the best is to export all packages that contain classes that your public methods will need. this message normally is a indication of a future classloading issue...